# Array search will not find space character

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to get user input and put it into an 1 dimensional array (I now know there are better ways to put user input into an array, I may clean it up later but for now it works) one character per element. Then step through the array made from the user input and look up that character in the predefined 2 dimensional array, element 3 to find the 3 "letter" color code that represents that letter, elements 0-2 (later I will use the same array to decode). The problem is, I can not get it to find the "space" character in the 2 dimensional array (if I enter a space in the input it is ignored in the output). I originally tried putting " " into element 3 but that did not work so I tried Char(32) and that did not work either, then I tried to explicitly put Char(32) into the input array, that did not work either. EDIT I tried " "C using both methods that I used for Char(32) with no luck. I have googled my fingers off and can not find a solution. I am pretty new to VB, Though I am taking an intro to VB class right now (this is not a class project, just a side project inspired by a biology lab, coding a sentence by stringing colored beads to simulate genetic coding, though I might show it to the biology instructor) but we have only gotten up to 1 dimensional arrays and are doing control breaks this week, 2 dimensional arrays will be in a week or 2. Here is my code, such as it is, it is kind of hacked up due to making changes trying to get it to work.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim inputString As String = ""
    Dim outputString As String = ""
    Dim codeString() As String
    Dim testString As String = ""
    Dim decodeString() As String
    Dim keyInput As ConsoleKeyInfo

    Dim index(,) As String = New String(,) {{"Y", "G", "R", "c"}, {"Y", "R", "B", "e"}, {"R", "B", "Y", "h"}, _
        {"R", "G", "Y", "i"}, {"R", "B", "G", "k"}, {"B", "R", "Y", "l"}, {"G", "Y", "B", "m"}, {"Y", "B", "G", "o"}, _
        {"B", "Y", "G", "s"}, {"B", "R", "G", "t"}, {"G", "R", "B", "u"}, {"Y", "Y", "Y", Chr(32)}, _
        {"G", "G", "G", """start"""}, {"R", "R", "R", """stop"""}}

    ' Allowed characters are c, e, h, i, k, l, m, o, s, t, u, "space", "start", "stop"

    Dim count1 As Integer = 0
    Dim count2 As Integer = 0
    Dim count3 As Integer = 0
    Dim maxVal As Integer = 0

    Const quit As String = "Q"
    Const code As String = "C"
    Const decode As String = "D"

    inputString = UCase(InputBox$("Enter C to code or D to decode, Q to quit: "))     'convert to upper case to eliminate case sensitivity

    If UCase(inputString) = code Then     ' get user input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter sentence or Q to quit (""start"" and ""stop"" will be automaticly appended :")
        count1 = 0
        Do While UCase(inputString) <> quit
            keyInput = Console.ReadKey()
            Console.WriteLine()
            inputString = UCase(keyInput.Key.ToString)     'convert to upper case to eliminate case sensitivity
            ReDim Preserve codeString(count1)
            If codeString(count1) = Chr(32) Then
                codeString(count1) = Chr(32)
            Else
                codeString(count1) = LCase(keyInput.Key.ToString)     'convert to lower case to eliminate case sensitivity
                maxVal = UBound(codeString)
            End If
            count1 += 1
        Loop
        ReDim Preserve codeString(maxVal)
        'codeString(count1 - 1) = inputEnd
        ReDim Preserve codeString(maxVal)
        count1 = 0
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
        Console.Write(index(12, 0) & index(12, 1) & index(12, 2))  'append "start" character
        Console.ResetColor()
        Console.Write(" / ")
        While count1 <= maxVal     ' look up input letter and output 3 color code

            For count2 = 0 To 13 Step 1

                If codeString(count1) = index(count2, 3) Then
                    For count3 = 0 To 2 Step 1     'set the colors
                        If index(count2, count3) = "B" Then
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue
                        ElseIf index(count2, count3) = "G" Then
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
                        ElseIf index(count2, count3) = "R" Then
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
                        ElseIf index(count2, count3) = "Y" Then
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
                        End If
                        Console.Write(index(count2, count3))
                    Next
                    Console.ResetColor()     ' reset the colors
                    Console.Write(" / ")
                End If

            Next
            count1 += 1

        End While
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        Console.Write(index(13, 0) & index(13, 1) & index(13, 2))     'append "start" character
        Console.ResetColor()
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()     ' keep output window open
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting project.

I rarely use arrays any more, instead opting for data structures like Dictionaries that lend themselves to lookups.

Here's an example that uses a LINQ expression and a couple of Dictionaries. The Dictionary.ContainsKey(" ") works properly so that should resolve your original question.

```
Sub Main()
    'allowed characters are c, e, h, i, k, l, m, o, s, t, u, "space", "a=start", "z=stop"
    Dim codes = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
                                                        {"c", "YGR"},
                                                        {"e", "YRB"},
                                                        {"h", "RBY"},
                                                        {"i", "RGY"},
                                                        {"k", "RBG"},
                                                        {"l", "BRY"},
                                                        {"m", "GYB"},
                                                        {"o", "YBG"},
                                                        {"s", "BYG"},
                                                        {"t", "BRG"},
                                                        {"u", "GRB"},
                                                        {" ", "YYY"},
                                                        {"a", "GGG"}, 'start
                                                        {"z", "RRR"}  'stop
                                                       }

    Dim colors = New Dictionary(Of String, ConsoleColor) From {
                                                               {"Y", ConsoleColor.Yellow},
                                                               {"B", ConsoleColor.Blue},
                                                               {"G", ConsoleColor.Green},
                                                               {"R", ConsoleColor.Red}
                                                              }

    Select Case InputBox("Enter C to code or D to decode, Q to quit: ").ToUpper
        Case "C" 'code
            Console.WriteLine("Enter sentence or Q to quit (""start"" and ""stop"" will be automaticly appended :")

            Dim sb = New Text.StringBuilder
            sb.Append("a")

            Do
                With Console.ReadKey()
                    If .Key = ConsoleKey.Q Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If

                    If codes.ContainsKey(.KeyChar) Then
                        sb.Append(.KeyChar)
                        Console.WriteLine()
                    Else
                        Console.WriteLine("(invalid)")
                    End If
                End With
            Loop
            sb.Append("z")

            For Each c In String.Join(" / ", From term In sb.ToString Select codes(term))
                If colors.ContainsKey(c) Then
                    Console.ForegroundColor = colors(c)
                Else
                    Console.ResetColor()
                End If

                Console.Write(c)
            Next

            Console.ResetColor()
            Console.ReadLine()     ' keep output window open
        Case "D" 'decode
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I am a beginner and I am using arrays (and this applies to other things as well) because they are what I have learned so far (even though I am using things that I have not learned in class I am not that advanced), I have no clue about data structures like Dictionaries and LINQ expressions, you are talking over my head. The real question, however is why is it that the spaces are not being picked up by the search? Again I thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: EDIT: I could copy your code, but I want to understand what I am coding.

Comment: No worries. In your source where you have: If codeString(count1) = Chr(32) Then // codeString(count1) = Chr(32). This condition could never be met and has the effect of never including spaces in the input string. Also, the line "codeString(count1) = LCase(keyInput.Key.ToString)" - keyInput.Key.ToString for a space gives you back the string "spacebar", not " ". You probably want keyInput.keyChar. I copied and minimally edited your code for these two changes and that fixed it.